# Пафос и патетика

Tags: семантика

А есть ли разница? Либо равнозначные синонимы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По значению это синонимы, восходящие к общему греческому корню. По употреблению несколько различаются ("говорить с пафосом", "патетика произведения"), второе имеет собирательный оттенок и, вероятно, образовано от прилагательного "патетический". В русский эти слова заимствованы из фрацузского ( http://newslab.ru/article/320808 ). А вот в современном английском слово pathetic чаще имеет пренебрежительный оттенок (жалкий, беспомощный и даже вызывающий презрение - впечатление от человека), поэтому слова со значением "пафоса" ("патетики") не имеют там этого корня.